# Grub and bootloading has strange delay

Tags: grub

On a new Debian 10 install (This happened with Debian 9 as well) on very recent and good hardware (Fast RAM, SSD, fast Intel CPU), I have a strange issue although not very critical.

When I first boot the machine and Grub loads and I attempt to cycle through the options, the first initial input (Up or down arrow on keyboard) takes about 0.5 - 1 seconds to register and complete. After this initial input, the responsiveness of the Grub menu goes back to what I am used to (instant response) on every other machine.

Then, when the OS is loading into the cryptsetup menu, it blinks a few times and waits 1 - 3 seconds longer before the "unlock disk" message appears, longer than than every other device (with lesser hardware).

Is there any reasoning anyone can think of this strange delay, it is not a critical issue I am simply wondering. I have not tried any other OS other than Debian 9 and 10.

Could legacy boot and/or UEFI have an impact on this?

Comment: I've seen similar behavior on my work laptop that's running Debian 10. On my system, the second delay seems to be associated with kernel message `ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM NOT RESPONDING`. Correlation does not guarantee causation, but my guess is it's related to the firmware and/or the kernel probing the USB-C ports and the functionality associated with them.

Comment: @telcoM interesting, mine has a message about the mmcblk0 (sd card)